# How to clear Cookies in WebView?

Tags: vb.net, windows, webview, uwp, store

How do you clear the cookies from a web-view in visual studio 2015.

The cookies persist through the code below and even through an application restart.

```
    Dim cookieManager = httpBaseProtocolFilter.CookieManager
    Dim cookieCollection = cookieManager.GetCookies(New Uri("https://www.example.com"))
    For Each cook As HttpCookie In cookieCollection
        cookieManager.DeleteCookie(cook)
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

The title of this question does not specify the question. I see two questions of which I may have an answer for one. The question mark at the end of the following quote leads me to believe that you are wondering how to fix the fact that the next user is already logged in:

> Navigate to a page and ask a user to login

```
Dim req As HttpRequestMessage = New HttpRequestMessage()
req.RequestUri = New Uri("https://example.com/login")
_WebView.NavigateWithHttpRequestMessage(req)
```

> They do a process and then they close the application
>
> Now when the next user opens the application they are already logged in?!

When the first user closes the application it is an event. Write code which resets the login state to false when the first user closes the application.

Comment: I am trying to reset the sandbox state so that the cookies and history of the webView are back to default (none-existent) each time the application loads.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to clear the cache using [WebView.ClearTemporaryWebDataAsync.](http://ClearTemporaryWebDataAsync). Some people have reported though that this isn't working for them.

The "old" way of handling this is adding a query string parameter, like a timestamp, to the browser. This usually allows the bypass the caching. So instead of navigating to *example.com/login*, you navigate to *example.com/login?stamp={DateTime.Now.Ticks}*